# How to configure LaTeX in Visual Studio Code to compile PSTricks or dvips?

Tags: pstricks, editors, dvips, ps2pdf, visual-studio-code

I would like to know how I should configure or what I should install to be able to compile graphics with PSTricks, for example in an editor such as TeXMaker, simply compile in the form `latex + dvips + ps2pdf` followed by viewing with a PDF reader. I would like to know if this type of settings is possible in Visual Studio Code. How to configure the `settings.json`?

Comment: @editors: Why did you remove `visual-studio-code`?

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity I thought it didn't make much sense to create a tag just for that, but since there are others, it's okay, I guess. I don't understand the purpose of the `ticks` tag though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file `latexmkrc` or `.latexmkrc` (Linux macOS) in your home directory with

```
$pdf_mode=2;
$latex = 'latex -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape';
$pdf_previewer = 'start evince';
```

For the viewer choose whatever you use with your system.
Then you can run the recipe `Recipe:latexmk (latexmkrc)` and you'll get the pdf.

[image]